# Having problem adding the admin module to my web application

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have my application running on the url say for example: http://mywebsite.com/
It is working perfectly. Now I want to add admin part to my application which will have url as: http://mywebsite.com/admin which will automatically redirect them to admin's login page(http://mywebsite/admin/product/login). I want this admin module work separately altogether. So I have following folder structure:

- app

  - config
  - controllers

    - admin

      - Accounts.php
      - Products.php
    - Homes.php
    - Products.php
  - core
  - models

    - User.php
    - Product.php
  - views
    -admin
        - products
            - index.php
            - login.php

    - products

      - index.php
    - home

      - index.php
  - .htaccess
- public

  - assets
  - .htaccess
  - index.php
- vendors
- .htaccess

I have three .htaccess files. And I am confused in which .htaccess file I have to make changes to make user redirect to `http://mywebsite.com/admin/products/login` if they go to `http://mywebsite.com/admin`. I have following code in all three .htaccess files:

** .htaccess (in root folder) **

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

** .htaccess (in public folder) **

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mywebsite/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

** .htaccess (in app folder) **

```
Options -Indexes
```

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.